# Firefox addon: Window.open() vs CTRL-N

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I created a simple firefox add on using addon-builder that installs & successfully appears in the add on toolbar at the bottom of the browser.

If I press <kbd>ctrl-n</kbd>, open new tab, open new window, or open private browsing window in firefox, then I see and can use my addon. However, if another site programmatically opens a window using `window.open()`, then my addon doesn't appear.

Is this by design? Or is there a setting that I can include in my addon so that it always appears, even if the window was opened through `window.open()` instead of <kbd>ctrl-n</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

When sites open with [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), they specify which parts of the browser UI will show. You may be able to place it somewhere less likely to be removed, like the navigation toolbar. The [add-ons toolbar sounds like it's going away soon, anyway.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en#!topic/firefox-dev/ua6yBQk0E_s)